# How to get subgroups in JSON Object Java Android Studio

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I have a JSON text that has some subgroups.
Here's what my JSON looks like:

```
{  
   "ID":"3684",
   "Equips":[  
      {  
         "ID":"3762",
         "Apelido":"P  Feira",
         "Serial":"PNZ45215554",
         "Geracao":"",
         "Atualizacao":"1899-12-30 00:00:00.000",
         "Alarmes":{  
            "ID":"2",
            "Data":{  
               "phhora":"12:00",
               "codequip":"12:00",
               "algicida":"1",
               "alcalinidade":"1",
               "ph":"0",
               "cloro":"0",
               "algsemana":"1000000",
               "alcsemana":"1000000",
               "clorosemana":"1000000",
               "phsemana":"1000000",
               "alchora":"13:00",
               "alghora":"12:00",
               "clorohora":"12:00"
            },
            "Mensagem":"OK"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get the "Apelido" from Equips, or the phsemana from the Data that is inside the "Alarmes" that is inside the "Equips". 
How does that work on Java.

I have tried the following code:

```
JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(result); //convert to JSONArray
for(int i = 0;i<dataArray.length();i++){
Log.d("TEST",dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Apelido"));
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way, I hope help you.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);

JSONArray dataArray = object.getJSONArray("Equips");

for(int i = 0;i<dataArray.length();i++){
    Log.d("TEST",dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Apelido"));
}
```

Comment: Nice, that worked for the "Apelido", thanks. Just another question, if I'm trying to get the "clorohora" for instance, that is inside the Data array that is inside the "Alarmes" array, how would that work?? I'm still trying to figure out how JSON arrays and objects work on Java...

Comment: The "Alarmes" is object and the "Data " is also object, not array. So, I think you need to understand more about JSON and learn how to extract JSON strings through examples on the internet.